# Viewport - jQuery selectors for finding elements in viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my project every div has a video so I'm trying to check if a div is in viewport, so if it is that video to start playing and if it's not to pause or to stop. I'm jusing jekyll. 
For example my html code for only one div looks like this :

```
 <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            <input type="button" id="play" value="Play"></input>
            <input type="button" id="pause" value="Pause"></input>
            <br/><br/>
                <div class="col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-1 col-sm-push-6  col-sm-6">
                    <hr class="section-heading-spacer">
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <h2 class="section-heading">Vjetersia</h2>
                    <div class="lead"><p class="justify"> Vjetersia</p></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-pull-6  col-sm-6">
                  <div class="gifv-player" id="">
                    <video preload="none" loop="loop">
                        <source type="video/webm" src="all_files/1.webm" />
                    </video>
                    <img src="example.png" alt="Animated Gif" />
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-pull-2  col-sm-2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I tried to do it on button click and it  works:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        player = new GifvPlayer();
        $("#play").click(function() {
            $('.gifv-player').find('video').show();
            $('.gifv-player').find('video')[0].play();
        });
        $("#pause").click(function() {
            $('.gifv-player').find('video')[0].pause();
        });
    });
```

but how can i modify it so it can work on stroll if a div is visible to start to play its video ? Any help?

Answer (score 1):

easy quick and dirty example how you could implement it. play/pause like changing colors of the `div`s ... http://jsfiddle.net/7mkdj4ak/1/

```js
var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
var windowViewHeight = $(window).height();
var videoWrapHeight = $('.container').outerHeight();

$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
    playVideos(scrollPosition);
});

$(window).on('resize', function(){
    windowViewHeight = $(window).height();
});


var playVideos = function(scrollPosition) {
    $('.container').each(function(i){
        var thisContainerTopPosition = $(this).offset().top;
        var thisContainerBottomPosition = thisContainerTopPosition + videoWrapHeight;
        if( 
            thisContainerTopPosition >= scrollPosition && 
            thisContainerBottomPosition <= (scrollPosition + windowViewHeight ) 
        ) {
            /* div is in view PLaY */
            $(this).css('background-color','orange');
        } else {
            /* div is out of view PausE */
            $(this).css('background-color','#afafaf');
        }
    });
};


playVideos(scrollPosition);
```

```css
    .container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: #afafaf;
        margin: 20px 0;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>my Video 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>my Video 2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>my Video 3</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>my Video 4</h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have a question how is possible for example on load if a div is in viewport to add that class 'orange', because your code is executed only if i move scrollbar?

Comment: also video is playing only if on scroll because if I stop scrolling even the div is in view port it stops  :(

Comment: @EgzontinaK I updated the answer, now the first `div` is also orange on page ready. See the changes http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32909731/revisions . I don't know how you included the `PLAY / PAUSE` code. But you could trigger a function where it says `/* div is in view PLaY */` to play. also check if it is already playing. I don't have time to code that all for you. also if you scroll back up do you continue with the movie where it last stopped or from beginning? this are questions you can answer in your code

Comment: @EgzontinaK did this help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this demo

```
.growme {
    background-color: #990000;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;

}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/adwb4q9x/6/)